# conditional print in a batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a very simple batch file that runs a SQL query file and copies the results to a printer.  The problem is it prints even if the results of the query is 0 rows.  How can I only print if there is data?

```
cd stock
sqlcmd -i testquery.sql -S localhost -U User -P password -o testresults.txt
copy testresults.txt \\printserver\share
sqlcmd -i ems_update.sql -S localhost -U User -P password 
del c:\stock\testresults.txt
exit
```

Ok, this is what I have now:

```
cd c:\stock
sqlcmd -i testquery.sql -S localhost -U User -P password -o testresults.txt
@find /c /i "0 rows" "C:\stock\testresults.txt" > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
pause 
) else (
copy c:\stock\testresults.txt \\printserver\share)
pause
sqlcmd -i ems_update.sql -S localhost -U User -P password
```

I cannot get the copy command to run now.  What am I missing??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a file that you know has 0 data.
`for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type nodata.txt') do set nodata=%%A`
Then
`for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type testresults.txt') do set test_result=%%A`
Then
`if not %nodata%==%test_result% copy testresults.txt \printserver\share`
This will only work if the same exact no data file is produced, like no timestamps.
**or**
use `find` which returns `%errorlevel%==1` if it does not find a phrase in file and `0` if it does.

Comment: Batch `if` comparisons only check string values, so that `if` statement will be false 100% of the time. Also variables in batch are called like `%this%`.

Comment: `set var_name=type contents.txt` will make a string with the contents of the file.

Comment: Nope, You'd need a `for` loop to process the output of a command. `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type contents.txt') do set var_name=%%A` will set the variable to the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - you can check if size of the file is 0. In Bash it would be something like this:

```
if [ ! -s ./testresults.txt ] ; then
  rm ./testresults.txt
  # or do something else
else
  copy testresults.txt \\printserver\share
fi
```

Comment: the problem with that is the file size is 1kb even if the query returns 0 rows because it writes that to the file.  The results I am returning with data will often be only 1kb as well.